# Not able to display all the data across navigation dropdown on hover correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hello I am new to NodeJs. I was making a website dynamic with the use of EJS and Node. I was trying to make a navigation dropdown which has three levels inside it like below.:-
[image: Live site]

Now I am trying to mimic this and this is what I am getting :-
[image: Local Environment]

The below is the code which I have tried in the js file:-

```
 MainCategory.find({},function(err, mainCategories){
      if(err){
          console.log(err)
      }else{
        app.locals.mainCategoriesHeader= mainCategories;

        mainCategories.forEach(function(mainCategories){
          var MC = mainCategories.slug;
          Category.find({mainCategory:MC},function(err,categories){
            if(err){
              console.log(err)
            }else{
              if (typeof categories !== 'undefined' && categories.length > 0) {
                console.log(categories);
              app.locals.categoriesHeader= categories;
             } 
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
```

Main Category is the first level, Category is the second level and the products is the third level. Not all Main categories have categories in them.

The data displayed by `console.log(categories)` is as follows:-

```
[ { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de132feae17c83f989afda1,
    title: 'Nuts',
    slug: 'nuts',
    mainCategory: 'fasteners',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de13341ae17c83f989afda2,
    title: 'Screws&Bolts',
    slug: 'screws&bolts',
    mainCategory: 'fasteners',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de13351ae17c83f989afda3,
    title: 'Inserts',
    slug: 'inserts',
    mainCategory: 'fasteners',
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16904acc2f532d4dca9c6,
    title: 'Brass Neutral Links',
    slug: 'brass-neutral-links',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de1691facc2f532d4dca9c7,
    title: 'Brass Terminal Contacts',
    slug: 'brass-terminal-contacts',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16940acc2f532d4dca9c8,
    title: 'Brass Earth Terminal Blocks',
    slug: 'brass-earth-terminal-blocks',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16963acc2f532d4dca9c9,
    title: 'Terminals For Connectors Earthing',
    slug: 'terminals-for-connectors-earthing',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16999acc2f532d4dca9ca,
    title: 'Brass Pin For Electrical Plugs',
    slug: 'brass-pin-for-electrical-plugs',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de169edacc2f532d4dca9cb,
    title: 'Copper & Aluminium Lugs',
    slug: 'copper-&-aluminium-lugs',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16a01acc2f532d4dca9cc,
    title: 'Battery Terminal',
    slug: 'battery-terminal',
    mainCategory: 'brass-electrical-accessories',
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16a2aacc2f532d4dca9cd,
    title: 'Aluminium Machined Parts',
    slug: 'aluminium-machined-parts',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16a5facc2f532d4dca9ce,
    title: 'Copper Machined Parts',
    slug: 'copper-machined-parts',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16a7bacc2f532d4dca9cf,
    title: 'Brass Machined Parts',
    slug: 'brass-machined-parts',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16abbacc2f532d4dca9d0,
    title: 'Forged Press or Hot Stamped',
    slug: 'forged-press-or-hot-stamped',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16ad3acc2f532d4dca9d1,
    title: 'Investment Casting',
    slug: 'investment-casting',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 },
  { itemtype: 'Category',
    _id: 5de16af6acc2f532d4dca9d2,
    title: 'SS Machined Parts',
    slug: 'ss-machined-parts',
    mainCategory: 'machined-parts',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

The below is the ejs file:-

```
<li class="menu-has-children"><a href="/productlanding">Products</a>
          <ul>
            <% mainCategoriesHeader.forEach(function(mainCategories){ %>
            <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="/category/<%= mainCategories.slug %>"><%= mainCategories.title %></a>
              <ul>  
                  <% categoriesHeader.forEach(function(categories){ %>                              
                <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="/subcategory/Nuts"><%= categories.title %></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/product/Hex-Nuts">Hex Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Flanged-Nut">Flanged Nut</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Castle-Nuts">Castle Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Hex-Jam_Nuts">Hex Jam Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Heavy-Hex-Nuts">Heavy Hex Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Square-Nuts">Square Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Furniture-Cap-Nuts">Furniture Cap Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Acorn-Nuts">Acorn Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Wing-Nuts">Wing Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Flare-Nuts">Flare Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Lock-Nuts">Lock Nuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/product/Hex-Coupling-Nuts">Hex Coupling Nuts</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <% }) %>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <% }) %>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

How do I display the categories for each Main Category and the product for each category.
Please help me out. I am stuck on this for a long time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for Each loop gives the last value. Remove this from the code:-

```
mainCategories.forEach(function(mainCategories){
          var MC = mainCategories.slug;
          Category.find({mainCategory:MC},function(err,categories){
            if(err){
              console.log(err)
            }else{
              if (typeof categories !== 'undefined' && categories.length > 0) {
              app.locals.categoriesHeader= categories;
             } 
            }
          })
        })
```

Loop through categories just like you did with mainCategory inside the else loop..

```
Category.find({},function(err,categories){
  app.locals.categoriesHeader= categories;
}
```

Then put the conditions to match the category.maincategory with maincategory in the ejs file below your ul tag. No need to try and match it with the help of for loop inside the js file.

Answer (score 6):

In your code, you have a loop:

```
mainCategories.forEach(function(mainCategories){
              // removed code
              app.locals.categoriesHeader= categories;
              // removed code
        })
```

Here, you are assigning a value to `app.locals.categoriesHeader` that is being overwritten each pass through the loop.  So, only the last category (`machined-parts`) is being displayed in your menu.

You may try changing the line `app.locals.categoriesHeader= categories` to be `mainCategories.subCategories= categories`.  Then in your template, instead of:

`<% categoriesHeader.forEach(function(categories){ %>`

You could use:

`<% mainCategories.subCategories.forEach(function(categories){ %>`

Comment: Is there any way I can get the current value. The navigation is working on hover ie if I hover on fasteners its showing me the categories inside it. ideally it should show nuts,screw and so on.

Comment: Tried it didn't help me out. Using app.locals to pass the value to multiple templates, in my case the header which is a partial. Anything else you can suggest if possible

Comment: If you look into the generated markup (for example, with Chrome inspector), do you see the categories/subcategories generated?  Also, if you can create a working example (either here on StackOverflow by creating a snippet or on https://codepen.io/ or somewhere) that would enable me to help you more effectively

Comment: The code is actually too vast and situated in different files to post on codepen. I am not getting value if I am using the code which you posted. My intention of using the for each is to get a condition match. Is there a way we can talk in chat ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you post all of it, just try to reduce it to the point that it still has the issue but all the other extraneous noise is omitted.  This exercise will probably help you find the problem on your own.  For example, just return the JSON directly as a constant instead of doing a query.

Comment: Unfortunately, my organization blocks stackoverflow chat, so I can't use it.

Comment: ok. I will try your suggestion out and get back. I will post where I am getting stuck at. Thanks :)